# Adding button w/ jQuery cause button submit

Tags: jquery

I am adding a row to a table. That works fine but the row contains a button that has a click() attached. Whenever I add a row the button fires. See here [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dbwink/ow3b6pjf/12/)

```js
<script>
//adds row to table
$('#btnSAS').click(function (e) {
   $('table tr:last').after('<tr><td>x</td><td><button class="btn btn-default btn-sm" type="button">blah</span></td></tr>');
});

    
 //delete row
$('button').click(function () {
   alert('delete');
});
</script>
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Header</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td><td><button class="btn btn-default btn-sm" type="button">blah</span></td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<button class="btn btn-default btn-sm" id="btnSAS" type="button">Add Row<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" aria-hidden="true"></span
```

Comment: You mean that whenever you add a row, the click **doesn't** fire? It's a dynamic element, and it needs delegated event handlers.

Comment: **http://jsfiddle.net/ow3b6pjf/11/**

Comment: when I add the row with the button the new button automatically fires. I don't want it to fire unless clicked by the user

Comment: @Blake see Ding's answer, your HTML markup is not valid BUT sounds like anyway you should delegate event

Comment: Well, you're clicking the button wherever you click, as you didn't close the button ?

Answer (score 2):

You are attaching a handler to **every** button, including the "Add Row" button:

```
$('button').click(function (e) {
   alert('delete');
});
```

So, it is not the button from the new row that is firing, but the "Add Row" button itself.  Both the `$('#btnSAS').click()` handler and the `$('button').click()` handler apply to the "Add Row" button, so both apply.

Your code before you edited the question actually fixes the issue, as it only applies the handler to the table buttons:

```
$('button').click(function (e) {
   alert('delete');
});
```

***However***, as others have pointed out, this will only apply to buttons that exist when you assign the handler (when the page loads).

This is a common confusion with jQuery.  You can only apply handlers to things that exist in the DOM (are already on the webpage).

The way around this is to use a delegate (assign an existing element to watch for the clicks).  In this case, you can assign the delegate handler to the `table` element, and then filter clicks based on whether they originated in a button or not:

```
$('table').on('click', 'button', function () {
   alert('delete');
});
```

In this case, any click that originates in the table is filtered against the `'button'` selector, and then a handler is called on the filtered results.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ow3b6pjf/16/

Comment: I was just adding that to my answer when I saw your answer.

Comment: Your fiddle still has malformed HTML and you'll need to modify the HTML in the `after()` to be valid.

Comment: Well, technically, the original fiddle had malformed HTML, and I simply fixed the jQuery issue.  :)  Regardless, I fixed it.

Comment: Thanks, its starting to make sense now

Answer (score 1):

It's a little hard to figure out what your desired functionality is from your explanation but going through it a couple of times I think I can tell what you're trying to do.

You're addressing every button in the document with your delete functionality `$('button')` but that isn't being updated when new rows are added.  Try something like this instead to apply that click listener for buttons inside of the table.

```
//adds row to table
$('#btnSAS').click(function (e) {
   $('table tr:last').after('<tr><td>x</td><td><button class="btn btn-default btn-sm" type="button">blah</button></td></tr>');
});


 //delete row
$('table').on('click', 'button', function () {
   alert('delete');
});
```

Also your HTML is malformed and doesn't contain a closing tag for the `<button>` and also has an additional and unnecessary `</td>` tag.

Here's an updated fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/ow3b6pjf/15/

Comment: Tried it and the added row button still fires. See the above jsFiddle link that's updated

Comment: I edited it a second ago after I figured out your HTML had some errors.  Try my modified version.

Comment: Ding, now the added buttons don't fire when clicked. Do I need to somehow reattached the click() function?

Comment: You can use the `on()` function.  I've updated it to reflect that.  Also see **Jeff B**'s answer which shows the same thing.